# Meaning of to go to their succour

Tags: word-usage

I read this in my history book:

> In fact, as DG Tendulkar writes, "Gandhiji was equally concerned with the sufferings of the minority community in Pakistan. He would have liked to be able to **go to their succour.**

Reading the definitions of the word "succour" itself alone, I can easily understand what the author want to say. But what I want to ask is whether the phrase has any idiomatic significance.

Comment: Kelvin, what do you mean by "idiomatic significance"? Are you suggesting the expression is actually an *idiom*? No, it's not.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Succour can be a verb or a noun, like its synonym "aid".

> He gave aid to his friend.
> He gave succour to his friend.
>
> He went to his aid.
> He went to his succour.

"Go to their succour" therefore means "go to their aid", or go to help them.